# The INSERT statement conflicted with the constraint

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, constraints, check-constraints

I want to make a date constraint in my table (I use sql server). I want to make sure that the date in one of my columns is later than the current date and time (I know it sounds weird, but it's an assignment so I have no choice). I tried to do it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE sales ADD CONSTRAINT d CHECK (Date >  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

but later when inserting DEFAULT into date column I get the following error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "d". 
The conflict occurred in database "Newsagents", table "dbo.Sales", column 'Date'.
```

This is the said table:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL  ,
ClientID INT REFERENCES Client(ClientID),
ProductNumber CHAR(10)  REFERENCES Product(ProductNumber),
Quantity INT NOT NULL,
Price FLOAT NOT NULL ,
Date TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
```

and this how I insert my data into Sales column and get the constraint conflict:

```
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @quantity int
DECLARE @prodNum varchar(20)
SET @counter = 0 
WHILE @counter < 10  
BEGIN
SET @quantity = (select FLOOR(RAND()*100))
SET @prodNum = (select TOP 1 ProductNumber from Product Order by NEWID())

 insert into Sales (ClientID, ProductNumber, Quantity, Price, Date )
 values(
 (select TOP 1 ClientID from Client Order by NEWID()),
 (select @prodNum),
 (select @quantity),
 ((select @quantity)*(select TOP 1 Price from Product where ProductNumber = @prodNum)),
 DEFAULT
 )
 SET @counter = @counter + 1 
 END
```

Is there a different way to do this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE sales ADD CONSTRAINT d CHECK (Date >  GETDATE());
```

change the Date  column to datetime

Comment: Already tried it and it gives the same error (I know that TIMESTAMP in My sql differs from the one in sql server). However is it even possible to satisfy such a constraint?

Comment: @BesSa change the column type to datetime

Comment: Yes, I changed it to :
"Data datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()"    

However I still get the error, the only thing that helps is changing the constraint from (Date >  GETDATE()) to (Date >=  GETDATE())

Comment: @BesSa maybe your are passing a date equal to getdate()!